# Duda NodeJS, importar módulos

Tags: nodejs

Estaba echando un vistazo a *NodeJS*, cuando me he encontrado con este ejemplo:

```
module.exports = function(app){
    var controllers = require('../controllers/controllers.js');
    app.get('/libros', controllers.findAll);
}
```

El caso es que este trocito de código va en el archivo **routes.js**. Después de haberlo probado, veo que funciona, pero no acabo de entender por qué se puede usar `app` como parámetro cuando ni siquiera ha sido importado.

Comment: `app` se pasa como parámetro a este módulo, no tiene que ser inicializado en este fichero sino que se le debe pasar ya inicializado (normalmente en el fichero principal: index.js, server.js...)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu pronta respuesta. Entendido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código que has publicado se ve mucho en aplicaciones construidas con Express. Simplemente estás pasando una *instancia* de Express ya configurada a un módulo en donde se mapean las rutas que manejará Express.

> No acabo de entender por qué se puede usar app como parámetro cuando ni siquiera ha sido importado

Pues **no necesitas importar directamente algo para poder usarlo**. Si desde el módulo B *exportas una función*, entonces al importar dicho módulo importas la función y *como toda función se le puede pasar parámetros*. No hay magia ni nada en esto, tampoco es una característica especial de *CommonJS* (librería para modularización de código JavaScript adaptada e implementada en Node.js), JavaScript simplemente funciona así. En Java por ejemplo, es igual; en la clase A importas una clase, creas un objeto y puedes pasar éste como parámetro en el método de otra clase.

Por otro lado, ese enfoque no es muy flexible. Es mejor mapear todas las rutas usando el enrutador que te provee Express:

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const Controller = require('../controllers/index');

router
  .get('/', Controller.index)
  .get('/:id', Controller.findById)
  .post('/', Controller.create)
  .patch('/:id', Controller.update)
  .delete('/:id', Controller.remove);
```

Así separas efectivamente tu aplicación en capas. De preferencia, **no añadas los handlers directamente en las rutas** porque no es responsabilidad directa del enrutador; la responsabilidad es de los manejadores y es buena práctica tenerlos en una capa aparte de modo que minimices dependencias entre ellas.

Comment: Vale, perfecto, ahora lo tengo aún más claro. Muchas gracias por la explicación que has dado.